# Error 'Could NOT find OpenSSL' in compiling ownCloud client

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-14.04, owncloud

I'm trying to compile ownCloud-client over desktop. But it gives the following error:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/bin/openssl ../client
    -- Build of crashreporter disabled.
    -- Could not find Qt5, searching for Qt4 instead...
    -- GIT_SHA1 71e8910e0261dca4933792b4e38f7d649409d6df
    -- If possible compile me with Qt 5.4 which is much faster/better.
    -- neon-config executable: /usr/bin/neon-config
    -- libneon has not been compiled with LFS support, rely on OS
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
      Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the
      system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_LIBRARIES
      OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "1.0.0")
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
      /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:313 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
      CMakeLists.txt:146 (find_package)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and openssl is installed in address `/usr/bin/openss`.
I also run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Debug" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/bin/openssl ../client`, but nothing changed.

How cloud I solve the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try installing the libssl-dev packages with

```
apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Yes. It solved the problems. Thank you. If I had enough votes, I would score your answer up.